# Complement of empty index vector is empty index vector again

Tags: r, vector, indexing, complement

I know this question was already posted but the answer was a trick to solve the given problem some other way, but the core question remained unanswered.

The question is this.

```
somevector <- 1:5
emptyindeces <- vector()
somevector[-emptyindeces] #returns empty vector
```

Why it is not the original vector?

Is there a reason for that or am I understanding it wrong.
If so whats the correct way to get the complement of an index vector.

Comment: Could you provide a link to the question you're referring to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`emptyindices` is `logical(0)` (logical vector of length = 0) and `-emptyindices` becomes `integer(0)`. So, you're querying the vector with indices of length = 0. You get back a length = 0 integer vector.

Probably you are looking for, for example, `setdiff`:

```
v <- 6:10
idx1 <- c(1,3)
idx2 <- vector()
idx3 <- 1:5

v[setdiff(seq_along(v), idx1)]
# [1] 7 9 10

v[setdiff(seq_along(v), idx2)]
# [1] 6 7 8 9 10

v[setdiff(seq_along(v), idx3)]
# integer(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thats because `-0 = 0`? But I can see how an algorithm can run into problem if this aspect is over-looked. So I suggest using `setdiff` instead of negative indices.

Comment: It's not -0. It's -logical(0) = numeric(0) (vector of length 0), different from -0.

Comment: Right, but thats really splitting hair in this case. Result of `(1:5)[0]` is same as `(1:5)[someEmptyVector]`. Thats how R treats it internally for array indexing.

Answer (score 0):

somevector <- c(1:5,NA,8)
sumvec<-subset(somevector,!is.na(somevector))

Not too sure if this is what you want, but let me know if you wanted something different so I can correct my answer. The answer hashtagged is an alternative answer if this is what you were looking for.